# Why are calls to `defmacro` evaluating to None?

Tags: macros, hy

I was writing the following pieces of code:

```clj
(require [hy.contrib.walk [let]])


(defn maybe? [command-text]
  (let [splitted (.split command-text " ")]
    (= (get splitted 0) "maybe")))


(defn if? [command-text]
  (let [splitted (.split command-text " ")]
    (+ (get splitted 0) "if")))
```

... until I realized I was doing something repetitive, so I wanted to factor out the pattern:

```clj
(import [hy [HySymbol]])


(defmacro command-dispatcher [command-type]
  `(defn ~(HySymbol (+ command-type "?")) [command-text]
     (let [splitted (.split command-text " ")]
       (= (get splitted 0) ~command-type))))
```

However, if I evaluate `(command-dispatcher "maybe")` in HyREPL, I get a `None`.

```clj
=> (command-dispatcher "maybe")
def is_maybe(command_text):
    _hyx_letXUffffX3 = {}
    _hyx_letXUffffX3['splitted'] = command_text.split(' ')
    return _hyx_letXUffffX3['splitted'][0] == 'maybe'


None
```

This is weird, because a macro should return a `HyExpression`, not `None`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your macro will not return anything but will define a function, as you can see here

```hy
(assert (not (in "is_maybe" (dir))))
(command-dispatcher "maybe")
(assert (in "is_maybe" (dir)))
```

An issue in your code is that you are using `let`, which is not available anymore according to [documentation](https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/language/api.html), here is a possible way to rewrite it using [`setv`](https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/language/api.html#setv) instead:

```hy
(defmacro command-dispatcher [command-type]
  `(defn ~(HySymbol (+ command-type "?")) [command-text]
       (setv splitted (.split command-text " "))
       (= (get splitted 0) ~command-type)))
```

You can then call this function using `is_maybe` (or `maybe?`, that's syntactic sugar), *eg.*

```hy
(command-dispatcher "maybe")

(print (maybe? "foo"))
(print (maybe? "maybe foo"))
```

Will print

```python
False
True
```

Comment: So, `command-dispatcher` was an effectful function which simply binds a symbol to a generated function and returns nothing useful. However, this behavior is different from those of other Lisps. AFAIK, their macros actually return a piece of code, rather than produce the binding effect.

Comment: `let` has been reimplemented in `hy.contrib.walk`.

Comment: @Kodiologist [you are right](https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/contrib/walk.html#let), I forgot to import it when testing my code, thanks for the precision.